# $A_4$ in terms of semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $N=\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2$ and $H=\mathbb Z_3$. Let $\varphi: H \to \text{Aut}(N)$ be $1 \mapsto A= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$. I want to show that $G=N\rtimes_\varphi H$ is isomorphic to $A_4$ (alternating group, I hope this is correct, if not please let me know). Is there any slick proof for this other than finding the 1-1 correspondence between elements of two groups? (the proof of homomorphism part is really annoying)

Comment: Alas, $H$ has order $3$ and $A$ order $2$. I think you want $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&1}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you! I edited it to the other one. But not sure whether the one you gave or the one I gave is easier. Both cases should be the same up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\text{Aut}(N) \simeq S_3$, which has a unique subgroup of order $3$. Thus, a non-trivial homomorphism $H \to \text{Aut}(N)$ is unique up to an automorphism of $H$. It is not hard to find subgroups $N'$ and $H'$ of $A_4$ isomorphic to $N$ and $H$ respectively such that $H'$ acts non-trivially over $N'$. An order argument implies that $A_4 \simeq N' \rtimes H'$, and, because the action is unique up to an automorphism of $H'$, we have $N' \rtimes H' \simeq N \rtimes H$.

---

The part "the action is unique up to an automorphism" is crucial here - check [this criterion](https://yutsumura.com/isomorphism-criterion-of-semidirect-product-of-groups/).